# Transfer many Gigabytes between two servers

Tags: ssh, sync, debian, ftp, migration

I have a big problem. I have to move data from an old Webspace which is only accessible by ftp.  The new root server is accessible by ssh of course.

I need to move *all* the data from the old space but the amount is just huge. Is there a way to move all the files directly from the old ftp to the storage and not over a third station (my local machine)?

I´ve tried it with ftp but it didn't work. I think I´ve used the wrong commands.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Fixed up the question, hope you don't mind. You can rollback the changes easily by clicking on the "edited X secs/mins ago" text. (About the tags, hope Quack will help.)

Comment: @shiki: go ahead and remove greetings ("hello", etc) and signatures ("Thanks, Bernhard" -- the "thanks" is ok to leave) when editing. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to call or e-mail the provider of the old system and ask to tar/zip the whole directory tree for you so you only have to download one file, which is easier, much faster and efficient then downloading hundreds of small ones. 
But if this is not possible the second best solution would be to login into ssh again on the new server, and install or use an ftp client from within the ssh session that does recursive directory downloading so you don't have to "prompt and mget *" all directories separately.

You can use "sudo apt-get install ncftp" if you have root access to install the ncftp client or upload ncftp3 client sourcecode and compile it yourself with a ./configure and make command

Alternatively you can upload and install the ftp clients yafc, tnftp or quftp to accomplish the same recursive downloading task (standard ftp does not support this).

Another route could be to recursively get the website via http instead of ftp assuming the website is still online or reachable with "wget -r -l0 http://oldsite/" through ssh, but there's a risk you will not get everything.

The last resort alternative is to download everything to your client, zip it and sftp it to the new server to unpack it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable direct ftp copy on both machine and that's all. Open the two machine in FlashFXP or some ftp client and copy between them directly. (If its not enabled on one server, you may want to ask for a temporary permission from the provider.)

(If the new server is yours, you can also simply use "mc" or "lftp" to copy files from the old space like its the ftp client.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi this Article was mine and I found a for me best parctical solution.

- I´ve installed lftp on the new machine
- created a folder which should contain the old ftp data.
- changed in this folder
- started lftp and conected to the old ftp server

entered mirror ./ ./

30 minutes later I had all the files on the new machine.

I think tis is an easy and fast way to etablich this.